# How to set the values which is inside the another message object as list

Tags: android, android-activity

I have Event Message object(EventMO)..In this i have event id,name,place,date,time.....I have another one called Event Reminder days message object...In this i have type id,is selected....I used Event Reminder Days mo as list inside the EventMO....

This is my EventMO

```
    private long eventId;

    private long ringeeUserId;

    private String text;

    private String place;

    private String eventDate;

    private String startTime;

    private String endTime;

    private int isDelete;

    private List<EventReminderDaysMO> eventReminderDaysMOs;


    public List<EventReminderDaysMO> getEventReminderDaysMOs() {
        return eventReminderDaysMOs;
    }

    public void setEventReminderDaysMOs(List<EventReminderDaysMO> eventReminderDaysMOs) {
        this.eventReminderDaysMOs = eventReminderDaysMOs;
    }




}
```

This is my event Reminder days MO

```
private long eventReminderDaysId;

private String eventReminderDate;

private int isSelected;

private int isMessageSent;

private int typeId;
```

This is my Check box code...Here i need to set type id as one for this check box....i cant directly use event reminder days MO..Because i need to pass inside EventMO as list to backend.....So how to set the value to type id,which is inside the Event MO

```
 checkBox_aWeekBefore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    final int response = 2;
//Here only i have a problem
                    //eventMO.setTypeId(response); ---i cant use this...it wont be allowed

                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                            return eventDelegates.addEvent(eventMO,context);

                        }

                    }.execute(null, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(OccasionActivity.this,
                            "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }}
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have coded for clicking on individual section, you can also get `id` inside this by using following code and also put it in your database.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int checkBoxId  = v.getId();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a correct way to get checkBox result, you need to add OnCheckedChangeLisenter in the place of OnItemClick.. I am giving you sample code for it....

```
    CheckBox chk1;
    CheckBox chk2;
    CheckBox chk3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        chk1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk1);
        chk2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk2);
        chk3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk3);


        chk1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Event Day Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        chk2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2 day before selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        chk3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "7 day before Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Update:----

just Check condition that Your checkbox is selected or not... if check box is selected then pass the method you want pass...

for example

```
chk1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b == true) {
request=2;
MOevent.setTypeId(request);
                 }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok.Inside EventMO i have list(EventReminderDaysMO).Type id is in EventReminderDaysMO....i want to pass type id through EventMO...how to use this

Comment: ok , first tell me , what is MOevent ??/ and what are you doing by setTypeId

Comment: I have EventReminderDaysMO(in this only i have type id)...in event MO i have eventReminderDaysMO list.......Here i am passing  those values by eventMO to backend...while clicking the on event day check box i need to set type id as 1....Now i am using eventReminderDaysMO list inside eventMO...how to set that type id..

Comment: Here type id is one column in my table.....if it is eventMO means i can set this..eventMO.setTypeId=1 ;Like this...Here the problem is i have type id in different MO....i am using this inside this EventMO....so i cant set this directly....

Comment: If i understand correctly , you want to add some id, in database, on particular check box selected

Comment: ya...... 
I have EventReminderDaysMO(in this only i have type id)...in event MO i have eventReminderDaysMO list.......Here i am passing those values by eventMO to backend...while clicking the on event day check box i need to set type id as 1....Now i am using eventReminderDaysMO list inside eventMO

Comment: Di you use DatabaseHandler as a Supporting class to do all Database operation

Answer (score 0):

Using **`OnCheckedChangeListener()`**, might solve your query. For further breakdown, follow the code snippet:

**Implement the `OnCheckedChangeListener`, as follows:**

```
class YourClass implements OnCheckedChangeListener{/.../}
```

**Enable the listeners to each Checkbox, as follows:**

```
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
cb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

**Override the `onCheckedChanged` method, to listen to the changes in checkbox's state:**

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    buttonView.getId();     //To get id of the checkbox
}
```

Hope that helps.